# Querying a database with an unknown number of parameters

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to query an existing access database and allow the user to pick multiple values for a WHERE clause. I've been using this code found on this site courtesy of user Mark Brackett:

```
string[] tags = new string[] { "ruby", "rails", "scruffy", "rubyonrails" };
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM Tags WHERE Name IN ({0})";

string[] paramNames = tags.Select(
    (s, i) => "@tag" + i.ToString()
).ToArray();

string inClause = string.Join(",", paramNames);
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format(cmdText, inClause))) {
    for(int i = 0; i < paramNames.Length; i++) {
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramNames[i], tags[i]);
    }
}
```

which gives this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tags WHERE Name IN (@tag0,@tag1,@tag2,@tag3)"
cmd.Parameters["@tag0"] = "ruby"
cmd.Parameters["@tag1"] = "rails"
cmd.Parameters["@tag2"] = "scruffy"
cmd.Parameters["@tag3"] = "rubyonrails"
```

This works excellently, but I would like the following functionality as well. If the user decides not to enter any values (in this example, if the tags array is empty) then I want all results to be returned. Effectively just a SELECT * FROM Tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
string[] tags = new string[] { "ruby", "rails", "scruffy", "rubyonrails" };
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM Tags {0}";

string[] paramNames = tags.Select(
            (s, i) => "@tag" + i.ToString()
        ).ToArray();

string cmdWhere = paramNames.Length > 0 ? String.Format("WHERE Name IN ({0})", string.Join(",", paramNames)) : "";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format(cmdText, cmdWhere)))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < paramNames.Length; i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramNames[i], tags[i]);
    }
}
```

So that if you have no parameters, you add no where clause at the end.

Comment: This is great thank you. I can also see that I could have several of these multiple parameter clauses in my query by having my cmdText as "Select * FROM Tags WHERE 1 = 1" and then use your code with "AND Name IN ({0})" etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try as

```
string[] tags = new string[] { "ruby", "rails", "scruffy", "rubyonrails" };
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM Tags" ;

string cond=" WHERE Name IN ({0})";

string[] paramNames = tags.Select(
    (s, i) => "@tag" + i.ToString()
).ToArray();

if(paramNames.Length>0){
   string inClause = string.Join(",", paramNames);
   cmdText=string.Concat(cmdText,string.Format(cond, inClause));
}
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText) {
    for(int i = 0; i < paramNames.Length; i++) {
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramNames[i], tags[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a single parameter for each item, why not just concatenate them?

I'm not sure if this will work in MS Access but here's what I use for MS SQL:

```
DECLARE @tagIds nvarchar(max)

SELECT * FROM Tags where @tagIds is null or tagId IN (select number from dbo.iter_intlist_to_tbl(@tagIds))
```

So `@tagIds` is a comma delimited list of Ids and I just parse it using a function. If `@tagIds` is null then all the tags are returned.

The `iter_intlist_to_tbl()` function looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[iter_intlist_to_tbl] (@list nvarchar(MAX))
   RETURNS @tbl TABLE (listpos int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
                       number  int NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @startpos int,
           @endpos   int,
           @textpos  int,
           @chunklen smallint,
           @str      nvarchar(4000),
           @tmpstr   nvarchar(4000),
           @leftover nvarchar(4000)

   SET @textpos = 1
   SET @leftover = ''
   WHILE @textpos <= datalength(@list) / 2
   BEGIN
      SET @chunklen = 4000 - datalength(@leftover) / 2
      SET @tmpstr = ltrim(@leftover +
                    substring(@list, @textpos, @chunklen))
      SET @textpos = @textpos + @chunklen

      SET @startpos = 0
      SET @endpos = charindex(',' COLLATE database_default, @tmpstr)

      WHILE @endpos > 0
      BEGIN
         SET @str = substring(@tmpstr, @startpos + 1,
                              @endpos - @startpos - 1)
         IF @str <> ''
            INSERT @tbl (number) VALUES(convert(int, @str))
         SET @startpos = @endpos
         SET @endpos = charindex(',' COLLATE database_default,
                                 @tmpstr, @startpos + 1)
      END

      SET @leftover = right(@tmpstr, datalength(@tmpstr) / 2 - @startpos)
   END

   IF ltrim(rtrim(@leftover)) <> ''
      INSERT @tbl (number) VALUES(convert(int, @leftover))

   RETURN
END
GO
```

See http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html for more information on parsing comma delimited lists. Although I imagine you would do this differently in MS Access

Comment: Thank you for this. It looks interesting and I will go over it later.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that if any of the tag is null

```
if (@tag0 is null or @tag1 is null or @tag2 is null or @tag3 is null)  
 begin  
    select * from tags  
 end  
else  
  begin  
    SELECT * FROM Tags WHERE Name IN (@tag0,@tag1,@tag2,@tag3)  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

put where clause inside a variable and make CommandText like `cmd.CommandText = SELECT + WHERE` 
when: `SELECT = "SELECT * FROM Tags"`
`WHERE = "WHERE " + "Name IN (@tag0 ....)"`
if no parameters variable WHERE will be = ""

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my existing. This will work.

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM Tags ";
        string[] tags = new string[] { "ruby", "rails", "scruffy", "rubyonrails" };
        string where = null;
        if (tags != null)
        {
            where = "WHERE Name IN (";
            foreach (string tag in tags)
            {
                where += "'" + tag + "',";
            }
            where = where.TrimEnd(',') + ")";
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(where))
        {
            cmdText += where;
        }
```

Comment: Well, other than the fact that this throws away the logic that calculates the number of values in the `IN` clause based on the number of values in the array holding the list of search terms, *and* that you would end up with something like `SELECT * FROM TagsWHERE Name IN ...`...